# Why and When to use Django mark_safe() function

Tags: python, django, django-templates, xss

After reading the document, the function of [mark_safe()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) is still unclear. I guess it is related to CSRF stuff. But why and when shall the mark_safe() be used?

Here is the documentation

> mark_safe(s)
>
> Explicitly mark a string as safe for (HTML)
> output purposes. The returned object can be used everywhere a string
> or unicode object is appropriate.
>
> Can be called multiple times on a single string.
>
> For building up fragments of HTML, you should normally be using
> django.utils.html.format_html() instead.
>
> String marked safe will become unsafe again if modified. For example:

Comment: When you can trust the content. I.e it's not HTML that was submitted by a user.

Comment: The docs don't mention CSRF, so I don't know why you would think it had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Django is a framework, which tries to do "the right" thing by default. This means when you do the most simple thing, you're propably doing the right thing.

Now let's look at some template in php and python:

PHP:

```
<? echo $foo ?>
```

May give:

```
<script src="evil">
```

Django:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Gives with the same input:

```
&gt;script src="evil"&lt;
```

Now assume, you want to place a link `<a href="link">text</a>`. Then django will render it as text using `&lt;&gt;` again. If you know what you're doing, you can now use `mark_safe` to indicate that the text is trusted (i.e. not coming from userinput).

Usually you will use `{{ foo|safe }}` or `{% autoescape off %}{{ foo }}{% endautoescape %}` in your templates as django programmer, which is more clear when the string is declared as being safe.

So, where is `mark_safe` used? When you write own templatetags or filters, then you need to mark the string as safe from python, because the developer will assume, that `{{ foo|mylinkifyfunction }}` does the right thing, i.e., it escapes the url foo, but does not escape the HTML code `<a href=""></a>` around the url.

An example implementation could be:

```py
def mylinkifyfunction(url):
    escaped_url = escape_url(url) # Take care of escaping the URL in a safe way
    generated_html = f'<a href="{escaped_url}">{escaped_url}</a>' # This string could be dangerous, if it would use url instead of escaped_url
    return mark_safe(generated_html) # mark the string as safe, because it should be rendered as unescaped HTML
```

The example assumes that `escape_url` returns a string that does not contain HTML or `"`.

Comment: So, mark_safe is to correctly render &lt;&gt, etc.?

Comment: mark_safe tells django templates that a string should be used AS IS, from your python code. Normally this is not what you want. Here is an [example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/222d0633010e2f37f9fbd2d0559ecc4a5643c738/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L481) where python code should output ``<br />`` for the template, which is not escaped.

Comment: @day **it escapes the url foo, but does not escape the <a href=""></a> around the url** and what does  it meant by this line?

Comment: @TariqAhmed I added an example for the example url filter to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

It's also worth noting that when building HTML code fragments it's advised to use [`format_html(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function instead of `mark_safe` and escaping all its arguments.

So, instead of writing:

```
mark_safe("%s <b>%s</b> %s" % (
    some_html,
    escape(some_text),
    escape(some_other_text),
))
```

You should instead use:

```
format_html("{} <b>{}</b> {}",
    mark_safe(some_html),
    some_text,
    some_other_text,
)
```

This has the advantage that you don’t need to apply `escape()` to each argument and risk a bug and an XSS vulnerability if you forget one.